# Elasticsearch reindex from 2.x to 5.x

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, reindex

I did an upgrade of my elasticsearch instance from elasticsearch-2.x to elasticearch-5.6 . Everything seems to work fine. But before i do an upgrade to version 6, I have to reindex data. Whats does reindexing mean?

I have a script that is creating all data i need on elasticsearch. Do i have to start this script. But in this case it would be the same like i would remove all indices and install all dumps back into elasticsearch.

I dont know how to try this because i dont know the "right way" to do it.

**EDIT**
I did now found the api with _reindex post. Do i have to do this for all indexes i have or is there an application i don't know that is doing this maybe faster than me :-)

Comment: What's your specific programming question?

Comment: i dont have a specific programming question. I just want to know what "reindexing" means in particular. I am still not sure if it is correct what i understood: Creating new index, import analyzer and mapping, _reindex from one index to another with _reindex API. Is this correct?

Comment: In that case, you want the superuser stackexchange. This is the programming one. https://superuser.com/tour

Comment: @G_V thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, why is this necessary: Behind the scenes Apache Lucene is writing the data. Lucene can always write its current version and read the previous one.

- Elasticsearch 2.x == Lucene 5
- Elasticsearch 5.x == Lucene 6
- Elasticsearch 6.x == Lucene 7

If you have upgraded from 2.x, you need to make sure that all the data has been written with Lucene 6 before you can upgrade to Elasticsearch 6.x. You can actually check this in the `version` information of all the Lucene segments with [`GET /_segments`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-segments.html) (this might give you a lot of information).

What you want to run to get this done is the [reindex in place](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/reindex-upgrade-inplace.html). And I can highly recommend the free X-Pack Basic migration assistant to make sure you have upgraded all indices and don't have any other hidden upgrade problems.

Comment: solved it already. answer is a bit late but thank you anyway :-)